# Programatically populate sample data for Django Image/File fields?

Tags: django

I need to populate sample data for Django Image/File fields in automated python code.

I want to initialize Django ImageFields and FileFields with some sample images and data files that are stored in my "site_media" directory of my Django project.

What would the code look like?  This is not for testing, I want to autopopulate sample data into my Django website user's accounts (including this sample Imgae/File media.)

This should be done in python code without using fixtures.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you want to use fixtures, basically a JSON formatted file that holds data that will be put into the project database. They can be executed through the django-admin command like :

```
 django-admin.py loaddata mydata.json
```

see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture

Comment: How would you do this in python code without using fixtures?